# Web.xml:welcome file displayed incorrectly

Tags: file, tomcat, indexing, config, web.xml

Welcome file is not displayed correctly on hosting.

web.xml:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
```

on local Tomcat:

http://localhost:8099/Teal-0.1-BETA/        **is OK**
equals to
http://localhost:8099/Teal-0.1-BETA/index.html          **is OK**

on hosting:
http://domain/index.html **is OK**

http://domain/   is displayed non correctly

As I observed this is displayed not correctly too:

```
 http://domain/index.xhtml
```

I suspect `web.xml` config. Looks like problem in `.html` vs `.xhtml` extension.

Real file name is `index.xhtml`

Comment: Do you have the `server.xml` available?

Comment: And, what does it mean, "incorrectly".

Comment: yes, I can acess server.xml on my hosting

Comment: incorrectly - means values such as #{request.contextPath}/page.html" was not resolved

Comment: Tomcat version is 6.0.14

Comment: @Ondra actually there is one more web.xml on server,Could it affect?

Comment: Oh. I see. Always remember not to post "doesn't work" - describe the actual error. And also list relevant software and versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you use JSF, but Tomcat renders welcome-file only with JSP engine. That might have been adressed in newer tomcat (7.x) which you have locally, but server uses older Tomcat.

But that's just my guess. Still I don't have much info.

Either case, try setting a welcome page to a plain file with immediate redirection to /index.html . Or better, handle it in Apache (or whatever you have in front of Tomcat).